# Sharing getter method across classes

Tags: java

I have 2 classes (A & B) as below. How to share Class A getter method value to Class B ?  Pls suggest.

Class A has `id` getter & setter:

```
public class A {

@Id
public Integer id;

public A() {
}

public A(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

---

Class B has `value` getter & setter.  Inside `value` getter method, I need to access Class A getId() value.  Currently, I am getting null.

```
public class B {

private Double value;

public B() {
}

public B(Double value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Double getValue()  {

A a = new A();
System.out.println("class A id value:" + a.getId());

    return value;
}

public void setValue(Double value) {
    this.value = value;
}   
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because you are initialising a = new A(); 
You are not passing the Id value eg: new A(123);